# PodSecurityPolicy malfunctions with specific ImagePullPolicy

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to deploy a Pod in my `v1.13.6-gke.6` k8s cluster.

The image that I'm using is pretty simple:

```
FROM scratch
LABEL maintainer "Bitnami <containers@bitnami.com>"

COPY rootfs /

USER 1001
CMD [ "/chart-repo" ]
```

As you can see, the user is set to `1001`.

The cluster that I am deploying the Pod in has a PSP setup.

```
spec:
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  allowedCapabilities:
  - IPC_LOCK
  fsGroup:
    ranges:
    - max: 65535
      min: 1
    rule: MustRunAs
  runAsUser:
    rule: MustRunAsNonRoot
```

So basically as per the `rule: MustRunAsNonRoot` rule, the above image should run.

But when I ran the image, I randomly run into :

```
Error: container has runAsNonRoot and image will run as root
```

So digging further, I got this pattern:

Every time I run the image with `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`, I always run into the issue. Meaning every time I picked up a cached image, it gives the `container has runAsNonRoot` error.

```
  Normal   Pulled     12s (x3 over 14s)  kubelet, test-1905-default-pool-1b8e4761-fz8s  Container image "my-repo/bitnami/kubeapps-chart-repo:1.4.0-r1" already present on machine
  Warning  Failed     12s (x3 over 14s)  kubelet, test-1905-default-pool-1b8e4761-fz8s  Error: container has runAsNonRoot and image will run as root
```

BUT

Every time I run the image as `imagePullPolicy: Always`, the image SUCCESSFULLY runs:

```
  Normal  Pulled     6s    kubelet, test-1905-default-pool-1b8e4761-sh5g  Successfully pulled image "my-repo/bitnami/kubeapps-chart-repo:1.4.0-r1"
  Normal  Created    5s    kubelet, test-1905-default-pool-1b8e4761-sh5g  Created container
  Normal  Started    5s    kubelet, test-1905-default-pool-1b8e4761-sh5g  Started container
```

So I'm not really sure what all this is about. I mean just because the `ImagePullPolicy` is different, why does it wrongly setup a PSP rule?

Answer (score 1):

Found out the issue. Its a known issue with k8s for 2 specific versions `v1.13.6` & `v1.14.2`.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/78308

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell based on the description. Do you have multiple nodes in your cluster?

At first, if you are seeing the error with `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent` and not seeing it with `imagePullPolicy: Always`, it's most likely due to having different container images on the local node than in the container registry.

It could be that you have an older version of `my-repo/bitnami/kubeapps-chart-repo` locally with the same tag?

Comment: Found out the issue. Its a known k8s issue --> https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/78308